# Clone HashMap<Weak, Weak> as HashMap<Rc, Rc>

Tags: rust

I'm trying to clone a `HashMap<Weak, Weak>` as a `HashMap<Rc, Rc>`:

```
type RcCell<T> = Rc<RefCell<T>>;
type WeakCell<T> = Weak<RefCell<T>>;

type SymbolRef = RcCell<Symbol>;
type WeakSymbolRef = WeakCell<Symbol>;

struct S {
    _some_list: Option<HashMap<WeakSymbolRef, WeakSymbolRef>>,
}

impl Symbol for RcCell<S> {
    fn some_list(&self) -> HashMap<SymbolRef, SymbolRef> {
        if let Some(ls) = self.borrow()._some_list {
            ls.iter().map(|(k, v)| (k.upgrade().unwrap(), v.upgrade().unwrap())).collect()
        } else {
            HashMap::new()
        }
    }
}
```

`collect()` fails with:

> the trait bound `std::cell::RefCell<(dyn symbols::Symbol + 'static)>: std::hash::Hash` is not satisfied
>
> the trait `std::hash::Hash` is not implemented for `std::cell::RefCell<(dyn symbols::Symbol + 'static)>`

I'm expecting for `Rc` to use its internal pointer for hashing in this case. Is there an alternative to `iter().map().collect()`? Or is there an alternative for `HashMap`?

Based on [users.rust-lang.org](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/hash-based-on-address-not-value-of-rc/28824), I tried to implement `Hash` for `SymbolRef`:

```
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};

impl Hash for SymbolRef {
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
        std::ptr::hash(&**self, state)
    }
}
```

But Rustc complains:

> conflicting implementations of trait `std::hash::Hash` for type `std::rc::Rc<std::cell::RefCell<(dyn symbols::Symbol + 'static)>>`

Comment: How do you think you will be able to populate `_some_list` in the first place?

Comment: @trentcl That's possible through `self.borrow_mut()._some_list.unwrap().push(...);`..

Comment: @trentcl Oops, instead of `push()` I meant `insert()`.

Comment: `insert` also requires `K: Hash`, which means you must solve the same problem you are asking about here. (Also you will need to use `Option::as_ref` to make `unwrap` work)

Comment: In any case, I'm not completely sure what you mean by "expecting `Rc` to use its internal pointer for hashing" -- do you mean you expect it to hash the *pointed-to value*, or hash the *pointer itself*? Either one is possible, but has drawbacks.

Comment: @Klaider 1) I'm still going to implement a `add_x` method to my type, but got stuck here. If the IDE reports I'm doing anything wrong with unwraping an Option, I can consider this `as_ref()` or `as_mut()` method. 2) Yes, the second, I mean hash the pointer itself.

Comment: I think the underlying issue is simply that you can't have `RefCell` as the key of a `HashMap` because if the underlying value changes -- which is the whole point of the `RefCell` (fake immutability) -- then you won't be able to find the key again.

Comment: @BallpointBen I use `RefCell` for field mutation only. I just asked the samething in [users.rust-lang.org](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/clone-hashmap-weak-weak-as-hashmap-rc-rc/66855/8?u=klaider) and one user suggested using a proper wrapper instead of aliasing `RcCell<T>` = `Rc<RefCell<T>>`. It did work, but `collect()` still fails with a `'static` bound.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I got was to wrap `Rc` and `Weak` into new types, allowing to implement `Hash`. The type parameter also needed the bound `?Sized`, otherwise my trait (`Symbol` in this case) would not be *object safe* within `RcCell` or `WeakCell`. To fully work, `Eq` must also be implemented like this:

```
impl<T: ?Sized> Eq for RcCell<T> {
}
impl<T: ?Sized> Eq for WeakCell<T> {
}
```

`hash()` implementation gets like this:

```
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};

impl<T: ?Sized> Hash for RcCell<T> {
    fn hash<H: std::hash::Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
        std::ptr::hash(Rc::as_ptr(&self._rc), state)
    }
}
```

This would be better for a crate on crates.io, though. There's rccell there, but it doesn't use a `?Sized` parameter.